How to read shapefile geometry with worldwind?
I am using NASA's worldwind library to read shapefile.
Shapefile s = new Shapefile(shpFileStream, shxFileStream, dbfFileStream, prjFileStream);
List<DBaseRecord> data = new ArrayList<>();
try {
        while (s.hasNext()) {
            ShapefileRecord record = s.nextRecord();
            DBaseRecord attrs = record.getAttributes();
            ....
            .... 
         }
           
}

I see that ShapefileRecord has no method to retrieve the geometry.
How to read record's geoemtry?

Got it. It has VecBuffer for that purpose. ShapefileRecord.getPointBuffer()
